# WPF ComboBox disabled item still selectable on border

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When I disable some combobox items they stays selectable on left and right borders of nested textblock.

[image: combobox screenshot]

I've tried to set margins of textbox and padding of combobox items to 0,  then I've tried set HorizontalAlignment property of textbox and combobox item to "Stretch", with no result.

**WPF:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ComboboxItemsDisableConverter x:Key="ComboboxItemsDisableConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,13,10,0" Width="441"
SelectedIndex="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedNic, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.NICs, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" 
SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
IsReadOnly="True" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="{Binding OperationalStatus, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxItemsDisableConverter}}" >
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**ComboBoxItemsDisableConverter Class:**

```cs
class ComboboxItemsDisableConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value == null) return value;
        var Status = (OperationalStatus)value;

        if (Status != OperationalStatus.Up)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What can I do to prevent selection of disabled items completely?

Hiding items works with this code:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OperationalStatus, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxItemsDisableConverter}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If I use this markup

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,13,10,0" Width="441" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedNic}"  ItemsSource="{Binding NICs}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" IsReadOnly="True" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
        
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                    
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Description}" IsEnabled="{Binding OperationalStatus, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxItemsDisableConverter}}"></TextBlock>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

no items disabled

Comment: Does it need to be IsEnabled, what if you use the IsVisible Flag to make it invisible when it's not interactable?

Comment: Unfortunately, "IsVisible" is readonly property. I'll try to hide items using style to change "Visibility" to "Collapsed". But I still want to know  how to completely disable combobox item, and where I made mistake in my code.

Comment: Could you add the Code of your Static Resource called ComboboxItemsDisabledConverter

Comment: Because the wpf code seems fine to me.

Comment: Starting message updated

Comment: If you go through the Class in your Debugger does he actually enter the false state?

Comment: Hiding items works, code added to starting message. Thanks MathewHD for idea.

Comment: @MathewHD Yes, it enter the false state. Disabling items works. If items are disabled it is not possible to select them, except of thin border around item text. I think it is markup issue.

Comment: In your DataTemplate remove the `ComboBoxItem` that is generated by the combo box's itemsgenerator. What you have now is double combobox item inside of your combo box  dropdown list.

Comment: @XAMlMAX please take a look to updated starting message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to disable the item containers content, instead of the item container.

You must understand that `ItemsControl` contains items in its `ItemsSource`. Usually this items are data models. Those models are than wrapped into a container. Data models usually are not of type `FrameworkElement`, they are plain data types. In order to render elements they must be of type `FrameworkElement`, that's why the models are wrapped into a container e.g. `ComboBoxItem`. You can layout the content of this container by defining an `ItemTemplate`.

You don't interact with the data model (the container content), but with the item container. When you only disable the content you still can interact with the container. The item itself has `Padding` applied. Therefore there is still enough area to allow interaction.

To solve your problem you must disable the container. To do so you have define a trigger or setter in the `ItemContainerStyle`. Note that the `DataContext` of this `Style` is the data model (the items inside the `ItemsSource`):

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
              Value="{Binding OperationalStatus, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxItemsDisableConverter}}" />
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

  <!-- Remove the IsEnabled binding! -->
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                    
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

---

Note that from a user perspective it is recommended to remove disabled items from the source collection using filtering instead. Don't show content that takes away space and doesn't allow interaction. It can be quite confusing, especially if the user doesn't understand the reason why the items are disabled and how he can get them enabled in order to select them.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<MyModel> NICs { get; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.NICs = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

    // Only show items where OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.NICs).Filter = 
      item => (item as MyModel).OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel  />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NICs}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: I recommend to follow the filtering approach of the last example.

Comment: The filter is only applied to the `ICollectionView`. This means only the control's `ItemsSource` is filtered, while the original `NICs` collection still holds all items.